# Can we use a nested else-if statement to assign a variable instead of nested ternaries in Swift

Tags: swift

In Swift, we can assign a variable directly based on nested ternary statements like so:

```swift
let result = (condition1 ? value1 :
              condition2 ? value2 :
              condition3 ? value3 :
              value4)
```

I want to use else-if statements instead, but it has pros and cons.

- Pro: reads better in my opinion
- Con: you have to use a separate `var` that gets re-assigned

```swift
var result
if condition1 {
    result = value1
} else if condition2 {
    result = value2
} else if condition3 {
    result = value3
} else {
    result = value4
}
```

Is there any way to directly assign an else-if statement to a variable in Swift?

Comment: You never had to declare `result` as var - since the value is only assigned 1x, it can be declared as `let`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Swift 5.9 you can now assign if-else statements directly to variables, making the expression more readable than nested ternaries.

##### Assign if-else statements to variables with Swift 5.9

Before, using **nested ternary operators**:

```swift
let result = (condition1 ? value1 :
              condition2 ? value2 :
              condition3 ? value3 :
              value4)
```

Now with Swift 5.9, using **else-if statements directly assigned to a variable**:

```swift
let result = if condition1 {
    value1
} else if condition2 {
    value2
} else if condition3 {
    value3
} else {
    value4
}
```

---

##### Assign switch statements to variables with Swift 5.9

The same goes for switch statements.

Before, using an **immediately invoked closure with switch statement**:

```swift
let animalSound: String = {
    switch animal {
    case .dog:
        return "Bark"
    case .cat:
        return "Meow"
    case .cow:
        return "Moo"
    default:
        return "Unknown sound"
    }
}()
```

Now with Swift 5.9, you can **assign the switch statement directly to a variable**:

```swift
let animalSound: String = switch animal {
    case .dog:
        "Bark"
    case .cat:
        "Meow"
    case .cow:
        "Moo"
    default:
        "Unknown sound"
}
```

You can simply eliminate that clutter, leaving you with much neater code.

Comment: Good answer. (voted.) I'm partial to the switch statement for more than 2 cases.

Comment: Also note that the Swift switch statement is quite powerful. You can switch on tuples, and have the cases select on different parts of the tuple, and add where clauses to those cases.

Comment: I'd vote it up, if the example at the bottom was more suitable (i.e. multiple if/else statements with different / partially related conditions). For the example you have, I would say the whole switch construct on a variable assignment is un-Swifty. It would be better to have something like `animal.sound` defined in or as extension to `Animal` enum itself, not where it's assigned to a variable.